# Libgdx disable scrollpane animation

Tags: libgdx

I have a scrollpane where I set the Y position and I want to disable the scrolling. This is my code:

```
// create root
VerticalGroup root = new VerticalGroup();
root.center();
root.bottom();
root.reverse();
root.pad(getPadding());
root.space(getPadding() * 2.5f);

// add some label's and button's to the root here
...

// create the scrollpane
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(root);
getStage().addActor(scrollPane);
scrollPane.setScrollingDisabled(true, false);
scrollPane.setClamp(true);
scrollPane.setOverscroll(false, false);
scrollPane.setFillParent(true);

Gdx.app.log("scroll max y", ""+scrollPane.getMaxY());
Gdx.app.log("scroll y", ""+scrollPane.getScrollY());
Gdx.app.log("scroll vis y", ""+scrollPane.getVisualScrollY());

scrollPane.layout();
scrollPane.setScrollPercentY(100);
scrollPane.updateVisualScroll();

Gdx.app.log("scroll max y", ""+scrollPane.getMaxY());
Gdx.app.log("scroll y", ""+scrollPane.getScrollY());
Gdx.app.log("scroll vis y", ""+scrollPane.getVisualScrollY());
```

I would assume that updateVisualScroll() does skip the scroll animation, but it doesn't. I tried everything and I have no clue why it still animates. This code is executed in the constructor of a screen. The Y-Axis is inverted, thats why I put the scroll percent to a 100 because I want to start at the top.

The logs are as expected:

```
scroll max y: 0.0
scroll y: 0.0
scroll vis y: 0.0
scroll max y: 592.0
scroll y: 592.0
scroll vis y: 592.0
```

Comment: Couldn't find the bug. Changed my whole application to use the default y-axis bottom -> top orientation. Now it works. Hope i never have to scroll to the bottom of a screen ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in order to know how far you can scroll in a scrollPane, libGDX subtracts its visible size from its preferred size. If the visible size hasn't been calculated yet (is equal to 0), this results in the max scroll distance being the preferred size, which is greater than how far you can scroll after measuring.

This workaround works for me:

```
stage.act(0f);
scrollPane.setScrollPercentY(100);
scrollPane.updateVisualScroll();
```